# Highcharts with swapping divs

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart column chart and below content for swapping of background color,if I click a column for ex: first column, below div's backgroundcolor and text should be swap,again when we click second columns again my div's backgroundcolor and text should be swap. similarly all the divs should be swapped onclick each column.If its possible with chart that is also fine. 
Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/hk7pm73a/2/

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>
 .layout{
 border:1px solid;
 padding:100px;

 }
 .green{
 background:green;
 }
 .red{
 background:red;
 }
 .yellow{
 background:yellow;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="col-md-12" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div class="layout green col-md-4">green</div><div class="layout red col-md-4">red</div><div class="layout yellow col-md-4">yellow</div>
```

### javascript

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',

    },
    title: {
        text: 'sample charts for both horizontal and vertical line'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 2,
        maxPadding: 2,
        maxZoom: 6 ,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
             'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return  '$'+this.value;
            }
        },

    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                radius: 4,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
       // name: '',

        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5]

    }]
});
```

Comment: I added a fiddle for you, but I honestly have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here if you click first column for ex jan,the color of all below divs should be change along with text ,again when we click on second column for ex: feb,again the color of all the divs should be change along with the text

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/1en2ozjL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook to the click event of the point in the series.

```
var colors=['.green', '.red', '.yellow','.green', '.red', '.yellow'];
            point: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    $('.layout').css('display', 'none');
                    $(colors[event.point.index]).css('display', 'block');
                }
            }
        }
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/samuellawrentz/xbbqb4ef/18/

Comment: Thanks for help,but here all the sections should be there and when we click just it will be swiping the background color with text.